# Azure SDK 1.8 CloudDrive

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-clouddrive

Where is `CloudDrive` in **Azure SDK 1.8** (October 2012)?

In **Azure SDK 1.8** the `StorageClient` namespace no longer exists. This is the namespace that contained `CloudDrive`.

I know that the `StorageClient` namespace was renamed to `Storage` in **Azure SDK 1.8**, but I can not find the `CloudDrive` class in this namespace.

Where did it go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud Drive access wasn't updated in the 1.8 SDK. See the discussion here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/01/known-issues-for-windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-for-net-and-windows-runtime.aspx

A quote from that link:

> clouddrive has not been updated to use the latest version yet and hence it does not support the 2.0 client library (which uses 2012-02-12 REST version). However, you can use both libraries together and continue using the older client lib for use with clouddrive (and diagnostics) but use the newer 2.0 lib for everything else in your app.

From personal experience, if you do use Azure libraries from different SDKs side by side in the same project, watch out for version conflicts, especially with the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration` dll - and watch out for NuGet helpfully upgrading your packages, whether you want it to or not.

Comment: This was my first post on any forum. I've always just used google and ended up looking at answers of existing posts. I'm not even sure who can see the comment I'm typing write now. If the person who answered my question can see this, why did you take the time to answer my question? Do you work for SO? Am I supposed to give you credit somehow since you answered my question? Not sure how it all works but I certainly appreciate all of it!!! Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe the FAQ will help some of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq  I don't work for SO. If you think the answer above addresses your question you can accept it, and as a result the reputation score next to my name will tick up ever so slightly. This mostly just inflates my ego and gives me a warm fuzzy feeling, but I'm a freelancer and so it also provides me with a way of demonstrating some of my knowledge to prospective clients.

Comment: When I click on YES for (Was this post useful to you?), is that how I accept your answer?

Comment: You would click the check mark to the left of the answer. See the bottom part of http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask (although the graphic is a bit out of date)